DELETE CASCADE MYSQL
Buen día, necesito hacer un query de mysql que elimine varios registros de 4 tablas distintas
(maestros, examenes, enunciados y respuestas)
pero yo necesito que al momento de eliminar un maestro también se eliminen los exámenes relacionados a dicho maestro, los enunciados que van relacionados a los exámenes, y las respuestas que van relacionadas a los enunciados, y me encantaría hacerlo con Join para no hacer tantas líneas y no quisiera usar el Delete cascade de mysql.
Dejo el query que he estado intentando utilizar
DELETE respuestas, enunciados, examenes, maestros
FROM respuestas, enunciados, examenes, maestros
INNER JOIN examenes ON examenes.idMaestro=maestros.idMaestro
INNER JOIN enunciados on enunciados.idExamen=examenes.idExamen
INNER JOIN respuestas on respuestas.idEnunciado=enunciados.idEnunciado
WHERE maestros.idMaestro=2;

actualmente me da error diciendo que la tabla exámenes no es única, pero he movido de varias maneras y me da errores distintos

No se si eso es posible (aunque mysql deja hacer cosas bastante raras).. pero ya de por si, ese from no deberia andar en ningun lado... las tablas estan repetidas varias veces, como se supone que sepa que procesar en cada caso?? y usualmente, si tenes que borrar de varias tablas, haces el delete en cada tabla, todo dentro de una linda transaccion... porque eso, va a bloquear media base de datos mientras se procesa, y no es una buena idea...

MySQL si que está raro. Las bases de datos relacionales usualmente permiten borrar de una tabla. Dí con la sintaxis correcta, pero el motor parece hacerse bolas con las relaciones, invertí el orden de las tablas en la cláusula from, a ver si eso ayudaba, pero nada, y no está documentado. Al final, da error porque existen registros relacionados (quiere borrar de examenes sin haber borrado enunciados, por lo que se ve). Te dejo un fiddle, a ver si te sirve de ayuda: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pF4pgfnbYfvu5C5dKuXLtQ/0

@gbianchi si, creo que tengo un problema con que aún no comprendo la sintaxis completa de un Delete From, de haberlo estudiado mas a profundidad tal vez sabría qué hacer y cómo, pero aún no la conozco del todo, y gracias por la recomendación en cuanto al bloquedo de la BD, creí que sería mas rápido y óptimo hacerlo en un solo query en lugar de hacer varios

@jachguate si, también cambié el orden, intenté con los alias, intenté varias cosas la verdad pero siempre me daban  un error distinto, y muchas gracias por el fiddle, creo que terminaré cayendo al Delete Cascade

La opción mas fácil seria realizar 4 consultas para eliminar de forma ordenada, respuestas, enunciados, examenes y maestros al final.
-- Eliminar registros en respuestas
DELETE respuestas
FROM respuestas
LEFT JOIN enunciados on respuestas.idEnunciado=enunciados.idEnunciado
LEFT JOIN examenes on enunciados.idExamen=examenes.idExamen
LEFT JOIN maestros on examenes.idMaestro=maestros.idMaestro
WHERE maestros.idMaestro=2;

-- Eliminar registros en enunciados
DELETE enunciados
FROM enunciados
LEFT JOIN examenes on enunciados.idExamen=examenes.idExamen
LEFT JOIN maestros on examenes.idMaestro=maestros.idMaestro
WHERE maestros.idMaestro=2;

-- Eliminar registros en examenes
DELETE examenes
FROM examenes
LEFT JOIN maestros on examenes.idMaestro=maestros.idMaestro
WHERE maestros.idMaestro=2;

-- Eliminar registros en maestros
DELETE maestros
FROM maestros
WHERE idMaestro=2;

Otra opción seria la de eliminar las claves foráneas de las tablas de respuestas, enunciados y examenes, para crear dichas claves foráneas como 'ON DELETE CASCADE':
-- Eliminar las claves foráneas actuales
alter table examenes drop foreign key fk_maesto;
alter table enunciados drop foreign key fk_examenes;
alter table respuestas drop foreign key fk_enunciados;

-- Crear claves foráneas con 'ON DELETE CASCADE'
alter table examenes
add constraint fk_maestro
foreign key idMaestro references idMaestro on delete cascade;

alter table enunciados
add constraint fk_examenes
foreign key idExamen references idExamen on delete cascade;

alter table respuestas
add constraint fk_enunciados
foreign key idEnunciado references idEnunciado on delete cascade;

-- Entoces podrás realizar el siguiente delete solo en la tabla de maestros
delete from maestros where idMaestro=2;

Espero te resulte útil.

Gracias, terminé habilitado el delete cascade, muchas gracias
